# Merge DateTimeIndex with month-year

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. One has a precise (daily) `DateTimeIndex`. I have used that index to create monthly statistics using `groupby(['groupid', pd.TimeGrouper('1M', closed='left', label='left')])`.

Now I would like to merge the information back to the original data frame. However, the date-time labels of the collapsed data frame do of course not correspond exactly to the original `DateTimeIndex`. So then I'd like to match them to the corresponding month-year information.

How would I do that?

```
                         statistics 
  date          groupid            
  2001-01-31          1          10
  2001-02-31          1          11
```

and original data frame

```
  date          groupid         foo
  2001-01-25          1           1
  2001-01-28          1           2
  2001-02-02          1           4
```

With expected output

```
  date          groupid         foo     statistics
  2001-01-25          1           1             10
  2001-01-28          1           2             10
  2001-02-02          1           4             11
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create new columns with month period by [`to_period`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.to_period.html) and then `merge`, also is necessary change `2001-02-31` to `2001-02-28` in `df1`, because `31. February` does not exist:

```
df1['per'] = df1.index.get_level_values('date').to_period('M')
df2['per'] = df2.date.dt.to_period('M')
print (df1)
                    statistics     per
date       groupid                    
2001-01-31 1                10 2001-01
2001-02-28 1                11 2001-02

print (df2)
        date  groupid  foo     per
0 2001-01-25        1    1 2001-01
1 2001-01-28        1    2 2001-01
2 2001-02-02        1    4 2001-02

print (pd.merge(df2, df1.reset_index(level=1), on=['per','groupid'], how='right')
         .drop('per', axis=1))

        date  groupid  foo  statistics
0 2001-01-25        1    1          10
1 2001-01-28        1    2          10
2 2001-02-02        1    4          11
```

Comment: Ha, the february date was a typo from me typing up the data (from a remote panel), you caught me!

Comment: I first 5 minutes find why there is not datetime ;)